# Is there an analogue of the open mapping theorem in algebraic geometry?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a dominant map of varieties. What conditions on $X, Y$ and $f$ are necessary to ensure that $f$ is open?

**EDIT** This argument does not work - see the comments: (Clearly, proper is sufficient since a dominant proper map is surjective and thus the image of an open set $U$ in $X$ is the complement in $Y$ of the image of the closed set $X \setminus U$.)

So I'm looking for conditions that apply when $f$ is non-proper, so in particular when $X$ and $Y$ are not necessarily projective.

Comment: Your argument for proper maps is not correct. There exists proper dominant maps which are not open. The usual condition for openness is flat.

Comment: @Mohan Can you give an example? (I know of an example of a closed, surjective map which is not open, namely pinching the middle third of a closed interval to a point. But I don't know an example in the context of algebraic geometry. ) (Dorebell: The error in reasoning is that $f(U)$ and $(U^c)$ may intersect, as happens in the pinching example. See here for more details: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239250/closed-surjective-map)

Comment: Same as yours. Take a smooth surface, blow up a point. The map is proper. But, remove the proper transform a curve through the point and the image of this open set is not open. It will contain the surface minus the curve, but will have the point added in.